# What is my error here, shows SQL syntax error?

Tags: php, sql, opencart

```
$upper = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE key='ndz_limit_up'");
$lower = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE key='ndz_limit_down'");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because, `key` is a MySQL reserved keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Please use a back tick against the word `key`.

```
$upper = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key`='ndz_limit_up'");
$lower = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE `key`='ndz_limit_down'");
```

The best option to avoid this kind of problem is that:

We should check MySQL reserved keywords while creating DataBase table fields.

And we should make sure that we are not making use of any keyword as our field.

**Ways to tackle with this:**

1) Use backtick (**`**) against table and field names.

2) For tables, prepend database name like: `databaseName.tableName`.

For fields: prepend table name like: `tableName.fieldName`.

This way, MySQL will interpret that the provided is not a MySQL reserved keyword, rather a database table or field name.

Comment: Thanks, do we have to put back tick on all column names, other than reserved?

Comment: Not necessary. But, yes, if we put, its better.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark it as solution so that other community member can gain.

Comment: @BigByte . . . The simple solution is to use column and table aliases that have no reserved words or special characters.  In my opinion (and others agree), backticks just make code harder to read and less portable.

Comment: Yes @GordonLinoff, I agree.